# Where can I find a free upload button image for an ajax file uploader?

Tags: jquery-plugins, uploadify

I'm using the Uploadify plugin to handle file uploads but the default button image is ugly. Where can I find free button images (particularly upload buttons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Buttonator](http://www.buttonator.com/) or [IconFinder](http://www.iconfinder.net/).

Comment: +1 for IconFinder, its like Google of Icons, and all for free